# How (not) to treat the surface of a precision ruler?

Tags: repair, tools, metal, repainting

I made the mistake of leaving my Starrett ruler in a damp, cold workshop and develop a small patch of rust. To compound this mistake, I decided to dip it in rust-remover.

As you can see, I turned my wonderful expensive tool into a batman villain.

[image]

Touching the surface with my finger, I discovered that the *surface coating had been removed instead of dirt being added*.

I have a strong feeling that fixing the damage done by my fixing is likely to end in me fixing the damage done by this fixing. However, **if I wanted to restore the original looks and rust resistance, how should I treat the ruler's surface?**

I don't have equipment for *galvanizing*, *electroplating*, or *powder coating*. *Anodizing* is out of the question since the ruler is made of steel.

Comment: Clear spray paint, the good stuff like acrylic rustoleam, will replace the lacquer with an even more durable water proof finish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polish and wax, or polish and lacquer, with the latter being closer to what you had at the start based on your description of a coating peeling off. If you've lost the paint in the numbers/lines, you might need to refill the numbers with paint before wax or lacquer. You need to remove the lacquer from the working surfaces (end/edge) to maintain precision without removing metal and causing different issues with precision.

Another coating possibility would be gauge block grease (pure lanolin, *i.e.* sheep's wool grease) which will also prevent rust, without messing with precision.

Or, send it back to Athol and have Starrett do that, but it might cost a fair fraction of buying another one. Or more than...